# Bash script background execution "the input device is not a TTY"

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm getting *the input device is not a TTY* errors while the below command is being run in the background of my **bash script.**  I saw a similar issue for docker, yet there is no single post for bash scripts. Is there any other option for running commands in the background other than using **&**?

```
echo "Starting the simulation server ..."

cd simulator-server && ./simServer-VegasMixed.sh &
```

Comment: In interactive use of `bash` you can run your script, then `Ctrl+Z` and type `bg` to put the job to the background.  Once you want to get it to the foreground again, use `fg`.  I'm not sure whether your question includes interactive use case, though.

Comment: Thanks, Mic, yes indeed my question includes interactive execution. The problem is, I'm using the script for automation installation which shall not require any user interaction .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally figured it out! I used tmux to run my command in separate sessions.

```
tmux new -d './simServer-VegasMixed.sh'
```

This [post](https://www.makeuseof.com/run-linux-commands-in-background/) has also helped me a lot in solving my problem.

Comment: This actually helped me while creating a new workflow for **Alfred** in _Mac OS X_ to open **Okular** using **Docker**

That was the main command I mainly wanted to run from **alfred**.
`docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=$mynetip:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v "$HOME/Calibre Library/":"/home/neon" kdeneon/plasma okular
`

Answer (score 0):

daemon turns any process into a daemon depending on your script you can try that.

There is always the option of using systemd and creating a service.  It really depends on what your script is.

Assuming you are running a linux distro (not BSD etc).  Create a file /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/simServer-VegasMixed

```
[Unit]
Description=simServer VegasMixed


[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/simServer-VegasMixed/simServer-VegasMixed.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=simServer.service
```

That will create a simple service that starts on boot, you can also control the service using

systemctl stop simServer
systemctl start simServer
systemctl status simServer

If you dont want the service to start on boot, then remove the WantedBy line.

If there is a server/service, then this would be the recommended way to have the service start.

Comment: Can you please answer the question specifically?

Comment: Not without knowing more about the script, and how you want it to run.

I am assuming it is a server for a sim, do you want it to start on boot? or manually?

Do you want it to restart if it stops or notify you if it stops? 

Is there any output to the script?  Any loggin?